# Ecommerce product information missing with Google Universal Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I recently upgraded to (Google) Universal Analytics but since the upgrade no product information is appearing in my Conversions reports. But, transactions do appear as do all of the other usual Analytics data. It appears that the 'ecommerce:addTransaction' is working fine but the 'ecommerce:addItem' is having problems.

Here is the js that gets written out on the page:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'XXXXXXXXXXX.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<!-- Analytics Conversions Tracking -->
<script>
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': 'WEB7014997',                     // Transaction ID. Required
  'affiliation': 'NA',   // Affiliation or store name
  'revenue': '0.120000',               // Grand Total
  'shipping': '0.000000',                  // Shipping
  'tax': '0.020000'                     // Tax
});

ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': 'WEB7014997',                     // Transaction ID. Required
  'name': 'Test Product | Fresh Air',                // Product name. Required
  'sku': '9999999-99',                    // SKU/code
  'category': 'RT',       // Category or variation
  'price': '0.050000',                 // Unit price
  'quantity': '2.000000'                   // Quantity
});

ga('ecommerce:send');      // Send transaction and item data to Google Analytics.

</script>
```

In the above I have split the script tags so that the top part can appear on every page and then the bottom part just appears on the order confirmation page. I have tried combining into a single script tag but this didn't solve the problem.

Could the hyphen in the SKU or the number of decimal places in PRICE or QUANTITY be causing a problem? Or is there just a typo that I can't see?

Any help appreciated!

John

Comment: The dots or dashes shouldn't be a problem because they are properly wrapped in the single quotes. Have you tried it with Google Analytics debugger?    https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en

Comment: No, but I will now!

Comment: Hmmm... no errors in the debugger but it does show this:   

    analytics_debug.js:9   
    <unknown>        (&ic)  9999999-99 analytics_debug.js:9   
    <unknown>        (&in)  Test Product | Fresh Air analytics_debug.js:9   
    <unknown>        (&ip)  0.050000 analytics_debug.js:9   
    <unknown>        (&iq)  1.000000 analytics_debug.js:9   
    <unknown>        (&iv)  RT analytics_debug.js:9   
    adSenseId        (&a)   1188481922 analytics_debug.js:9   
    apiVersion       (&v)   1 analytics_debug.js:9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John, everything seems to be fine except the number-formats. Make sure you include only 2 decimal places, with quantity being  a whole number. I am pretty sure this might be causing the issues.

Comment: Okay, will try thanks. Annoyingly that is how the e-commerce platforms spits out the values. I guess I'll have to add in some javascript to round them off.

Comment: Simply JS should do... please let me know if this helped. :)

Comment: Ive added in the rounding off but it still looks like its messed up when I use GA Debug:  
  
 analytics_debug.js:9  
<unknown>        (&ic)  9999999-99 analytics_debug.js:9  
<unknown>        (&in)  Test Product | Fresh Air analytics_debug.js:9  
<unknown>        (&ip)  0.05 analytics_debug.js:9  
<unknown>        (&iq)  1 analytics_debug.js:9  
<unknown>        (&iv)  RT analytics_debug.js:9  
adSenseId        (&a)   1064725295 analytics_debug.js:9

Comment: Good grief, I wish I knew how to do line returns in comments!!

Comment: John, just send a link :)

Comment: It only appears on the order confirmation page so you'd have to buy something ;)

Comment: Here's a html page with the output from GA Debug (part of) formatted a  bit easier to read: http://www.tintami.co.uk/dev/tmp/codesnippet.html

Comment: The parts that say <unknown> should be things like "sku" and "price" etc. Bizarre! At least the prices and quantities are coming out with the correct number of decimal places now.

Comment: So is it working now?

Comment: YES!! Sorry for the delay... just needed a while before the stats started coming into analytics again. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help :)